# Android. Using resources from dynamically loaded jar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, dynamic-class-loaders

My last hope ever:)

I'm developping an Android application for the drivers of a taxi service. Many updates can happen during a lifitime of this product so we want to try to maintain them by internal means of application. So i wrote a launcher that reads jar over internet, I got rid of launching dinamically loaded code with the help of DexClassLoader. I use base activity registered through manifest, but it uses a kind of adapters loaded dynamically for performing actual code.

Such simple adapter is successfully linked to activity and gets executed. But I have failed also setting layout dynamically with setContentView(). I manually placed all R-files into dynamically loaded jar-file, but I still hadn't find a solution how to use those resources.

Isn't there really a way to do this? If no, I think it's a big joke: one can load and execute almost any code dynamically from external locations but he can't use resources from such locations:(

Comment: I don't know how do it, But i found this app doing it. It downloads apk, parses it, and then run it, without installing it. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I visited this app's page at Google Play, it's really interesting. But that's quite another story, I think.

Comment: I communicated to the author of an article covering tasks similar to mine, and he kindly helped me with some ideas and sample code. Now all works fine.

Comment: @ dmitri novikov, If possible, Can you share code (or atleast theory) as answer to this question. ( That's how stackoverflow grows :-) )

Comment: Palani, I can. But not right now. This requires some time, 'cause it's used in the written code, but not in my memory:) I'll try to post a rather complete answer to my question tomorrow or on Sunday, ok?

Comment: @DmitriNovikov  hi, can you share some sample code?